# Multiple string environment variables and Spring jee:jndi-lookup

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables

I have the following configuration in my spring xml:

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup expected-type="java.lang.String" id="isTestSystem" jndi-name="java:comp/env/isTestSystem" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup expected-type="java.lang.String" id="webURL" jndi-name="java:comp/env/webURL" />
```

And those are `@Autowired` into the code:

```
@Autowired private String webURL = null;
@Autowired private String isTestSystem = null;
```

Their getters and setters are standard get() and set(). I'm getting the following message:

```
[Time: 09 Apr 2023 09:29:17,438][Thread: main][Log: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext][Level: WARN ] - [File: AbstractApplicationContext.java:591] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter#0' defined in class path resource [eSolutions/eSolutions-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'appConfig' while setting bean property 'attributes' with key [TypedStringValue: value [appBean], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'homePage'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: isTestSystem,webURL
```

It appears to be complaining that there are 2 string values available in the naming environment but I can't understand why. Any ideas?